# Rudimentary File Explorer Using Dialog Boxes with FSELECT: Bash and Loop?

Tags: linux, bash, loops

Hello I want to create a file manager and so far this is what I have achieved.

```
#!/bin/bash

function quit {
        exit 0
}

function menu {
        choice=$(dialog --backtitle "Probe" \
                --title "Main Menu" \
                --clear \
                --nocancel \
                --fselect /home/myname 10 20)
}
exit 1
```

Problem is when i enter this into the terminal it does not come out -> The dialog Box doesnt appear :c

My goal is to create something like this [picture] with later multiple more functions than cancel and ok [Tips how I can do that?]

- How i Want my file manager to be[How i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooK7o.png)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Almost but not quite.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function menu {
   dialog --backtitle "Probe" \
   --title "Main Menu" \
   --clear \
   --nocancel \
  --fselect /home/myname 10 20
}

menu
```